# Android Webview scroll is misbehaving when loading a flash website

Tags: android, flash, adobe, android-webview

I am opening a simple flash based website in my webview using following code:

**Java Code:**

```
package com.sample.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SampleWebViewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("loading");

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progress.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progress.dismiss();
            }
        });

        Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/features/#linkedcharts-for-easy-drill-down");
            }
        });   
    }
}
```

Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Load URL" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now when the page is loaded completely and i am trying to scroll down to view rest of the content, the webview is coming on top of "Load URL" button. Check the screenshot:

[image]

while it should look like:

[image]

Please suggest, what should i do so that it works correctly.

**Edit: I am using a Galaxy Note(OSv2.3.5) with the latest version of both Flash Player and Adobe Air installed.**

Comment: Please check if this question is not describing identical problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418115/android-flash-content-breaks-webview-boundings-and-overlaps-native-layout-eleme

Comment: yes.. somehow. but it was an older thread and also the bug mentioned in adobe bug base is showing as "Closed". So i think devs may have find a solution for this problem.

Comment: As adobe is abandoning flash on android next month, you should probably focus instead on transitioning to something else.

Answer (score 2):

I have also tried this things but I think the only solution to do this is by using only a single webview in your xml, so, you don't have other native controls.

Answer (score 0):

This is really broken on Android. If you try to use the Build in topbar it will also go behind the flash. I'd really recommend you go away (far away) from flash. There is some discussions about it on google groups and some on stackoverflow but all ends without any good results. The only good suggestion I found was using flash to cover other flash components =/